# cancelled cp command deleted source files

Tags: server, data-recovery

I am loosing my mind...
I was doing a backup of some of my most important files (family photos and videos) to another server.

I used the cp command to backup from a ZFS mount. All was going fine until I realized there was not enough free space on the target server. I canceled the cp command using ctrl c

When I went back to the main server and listed the files some of the directories were missing. After a few minutes I did ls again and all the directories were gone.

Any help here to recover those files would be huge.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.3 and the files were on a ZFS pool. I do have snapshots but I added a bunch of new files last night so I prefer not to have to recover using the snapshot that is a couple weeks old.

Please help if you can. I need a way to recover these files. I have shutdown the server to avoid any files being overwritten.

I don't understand why these files would have been removed. I was using cp command not mv.

Comment: I just realized why it all deleted. When I cancelled the cp command I was in the mounted directory, not the target directory and I thought I was deleting the files that had copied not the original location. Am I completely screwed?